# Function to get a value between 1 and N using DateTime.DayOfYear Property

Tags: c#, sql-server, algorithm, datetime, modulo

I'm developing an application that has a table with N rows. I'm using C# and SQL Server.

I have to retrieve a different row each day. For example, on December, 22nd, I have to retrieve row 1. On December, 23rd, I have to retrieve row 2, etc.

I need a function that returns a number from 1 to N, using [DateTime.DayOfYear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofyear.aspx) Property to get it.

Maaybe I need to do something like this `(DateTime.DayOfYear mod N)`, to do what I want to do.

What do I have to do?

Comment: Do you want the rows to be random, or always the same for that day.  I.E. December 23rd will always return 2?  How big is N?  Is it greater or larger then 365?  What do you want to do about leap years?

Comment: I want to get first row 1, tomorrow row 2, next row 3, ..., next row N, and start over again with row 1. I don't want to get the same row on the same day.

Comment: Sample input and expected output?

Comment: Simple input: day of the year. Sample output: a number between 1 and N.

Comment: Thanks for down voting a don't tell why. Very instructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DateTime.ToOADate()` to get a number value.

```
var today = DateTime.Today.ToOADate();
return today % N;
```

If you want to do it in a SQL query, I am sure there is some similar function like `ToOADate()`.

For details about OADate(), here is the documentation. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
var today = DateTime.Now().DayOfYear;
return today % N + 1;

This will get you a number between 1 and N.  If you don't use the + 1 it will be between 0 and N - 1.  If your SQL Server has N rows and an identity column you can just

select *
from my_table
where my_parameter = my_identity;
```

Just pass in the result fo the c# function to the sql command as a parameter and you should be good to go.